# %3F doesn't redirect in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

this is my rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule ^ttnews.php(.*) / [R=301,L]
```

This is the URL i'm opening:
http://partnerlift.localhost.de/ttnews.php%3Fcat%3D3%26uid%3D197%26startResult%3D0

But it doesn't redirect. What's the mistake?

Comment: The link shows that you are using IIS. Why do you tag it with [tag:.htaccess] and [tag:mod-rewrite] and why are you trying to use a Apache configuration file?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a [[NE]](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/flags.html)
 flag to your rule

```
RewriteRule ^ttnew\.php(.*)$ / [R=301,L,NE]
```